# Preventing bubble of click from a knockout checked binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

With this fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/5skHX/

...notice when the 'click me' link is clicked, the tbody element processes the click event bubbled from the td element.  However, when you click the checkbox, the click handler is still called.  How do I prevent the click event from bubbling from the checkbox?

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: itemSelected" />
            </td>
            <td>[Click me]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="clicks" data-bind="text: clicks"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function Model() {
    var self = this;
    self.value = ko.observable();
    self.clicks = ko.observable(0);
    self.itemSelected = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.value();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            self.value(value);
            return true;
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });
}
var model = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(model);

$('tbody').click(function () {
    model.clicks(model.clicks() + 1);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that but returning 'true' from my handler didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You need both the `click: function() { return true; }, clickBubble: false` : http://jsfiddle.net/Q8sRF/

Comment: Yes!  That's the answer. thx!

Answer (score -2):

```
...
<td id="clickmeID">[Click me]</td>
...
```

and

```
$('#clickmeID').click(function () {
model.clicks(model.clicks() + 1);
});
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: That works, but for this solution, I need the click handler to be attached to tbody.

Comment: This is not the correct answer to use with Knockout.